# How to share new widget variable to parent class that spawned it in QT Creator

Tags: c++, qt

I have one class that is responsbile for device configuration. In this class, I have a UI window that appears when a button is pressed. This UI window is a configuration window where the user can insert two float values. I want to save these float values to the parent class. I did not realise that in QT, the program continues in some loop once the window is open, so I can't necessarily create a "Get" function, as by the time I close the window, the instance is destroyed.

foo_ui.h

```c++
namespace Ui {
class foo;
}

class foo : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit foo(QWidget *parent = 0, instrument_class *instrument=0);
    ~foo();

signals:
    void openWindow(foo *obj);

private:
    struct varsToUpdate{
        float A;
        float B;
        Qstring D;
        int F;
    }
}
```

bar_ui.h

```c++
namespace Ui {
class bar;
}

class bar : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit bar(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~bar();

private:
    typedef struct  {
        float A;
        float B;
    } userData;
}
```

foo_ui.cpp

```c++
foo::foo(QWidget *parent, instrument_class *instrument) :
    QFrame(parent),
    ui(new Ui::foo)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

void foo::on_btnSaveFoo_clicked()
{
    ClassB *bar = new ClassB(); // I want to pass some pointer to the foo class so it can directly update variables from within that class.

    bar->show(); // spawns new window that can take 2 floats

    // Then once the bar window is closed, save the variables into the foo struct
    VarsToUpdate varsToUpdate;
    varsToUpdate.A = returnedFloatValue.A;
    varsToUpdate.B = returnedFloatValue.B;
}
```

bar_ui.c

```c++
bar::bar(QWidget *parent, foo *obj) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::bar)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    ui->lineEdit_A->setText("0.0000");
    ui->lineEdit_B-userData>setText("0.0000");

    connect(this, SIGNAL(sig_UserDataUpdateBox(QString, QString)), this, SLOT(sl_UserDataUpdateBox(QString,QString)),Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

bar::~bar()
{
    delete ui;
}

void bar::on_btnClose_clicked()
{
    this->close();
}

void bar::on_btnSaveBar_clicked()
{
    // Save data here
    userData userdata;

    userdata.A = ui->lineEdit_A->text().toFloat();
    userdata.B = ui->lineEdit_B->text().toFloat();

    emit sig_UserDataUpdateBox( "Data Updated", "Config update applied.");
    this->close();
}
```

Now, in `foo::on_btnSaveFoo_clicked()` I have tried to make a signal with the logic that "when save is clicked in the other window, save the variables" but I get compile errors regarding syntax of the signals. I feel like I am on the right path of trying signals and slots, however I can't seem to get it right in working over two diferent classes.

I've also attempted passing a pointer to the parent class by modifying the `bar` constructor to `bar(QWidget *parent = nullptr, foo *obj = 0);`, but I recieve `Syntax error: identifier when I try to pass in a pointer to the UI configuration class.

UI looks something like where ClassA = `foo`, and ClassB = `bar`:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do following:

1. Override [void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#closeEvent) method in class B. In this method emit some signal with the value entered for `Var A` and `Var B` fields
2. In class A, connect to the signal of class B and catch values accordingly

**Note:** You must call `event->accept();` after emitting the signal in `void QWidget::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)` method